# How to install Ubuntu with Windows 8.1 without formatting any partition?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have laptop running Windows 8.1 with single SSD of 128 GB. I have 2 partitions. C:/ has windows and D:/ is also filled with files. I can make space in D:/ driver around 20 GB.

Can I install Ubuntu along with Windows without formatting any partition and loosing any data?

Can I install it in remaining space in drive D:/ without moving it's all other files to some other External HDD?

How much space Ubuntu for Desktop can take in HDD?

Comment: The system requirements for Ubuntu are on the Ubuntu website.

Answer (score 0):

**HOW MUCH HARD DISK SPACE UBUNTU INSTALLATION TAKES**

Ubuntu requires a minimum of 6 GB of space for installation. As you are saying you have 20 GB available, it is more than enough and Ubuntu can be easily installed!

**CAN I INSTALL IT IN DRIVE D'S REMAINING SPACE**

Well, you cant just install it on Drive D. You have to first shrink the partition. To do it, follow the steps:

1. Go to *Charms* and hit *Search*. Now enter *Create and Format Hard Disk Partitions*. Click on the first link in the search.
2. You now have to provide administrative access. When done, in the new Window that launches right click your *desired partition (in this case D)* and click *Shrink*.
3. In the new window, after Disk Engagement queries the drive for available space, enter the amount you want to shrink. Make sure you have that much free space available prior to shrinking.
4. When entered, click *shrink*.

Now that you have **successfully shrunk the space and created a separate partition for Ubuntu** you can now install Ubuntu on it, without losing you data or creating a backup of it on another hard drive.